# interfaces having same function prototype in java?

Tags: java, interface

I have implemented two interfaces with same method names and signatures in a single class then how the compiler will identify the which method is for which interface?

E.X:

```
           public interface Hourly{
              int calculate_salary();
            }

           public interface Fixed{
              int calculate_salary();
            }

           public class Employee implements Hourly, Fixed{   
              public static void main(String... args) throws Exception{   

              }

              @Override
              int calculate_salary(){  // from which interface Hourly or Fixed???
                return 0;
              }
            }
```

this problem has solution in C# but it did not work that way in java please help

thanks

Comment: It implements the method for both of them.

Comment: As an aside, you have a fundamental design problem here. Your class structure is saying that ALL your employees are BOTH hourly AND fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**There is no choice to be made.**

There can only be one actual implementation of this method, and it will be called. The fact that the class implements two interfaces that both force it to have such a method doesn't meant that there must be (or can be) two such methods. The existence of the one method satisfies the conditions imposed by both interfaces.

Comment: there should be some way to implement both interfaces in java

Comment: Only if you wanted to *create* the problem you are trying to ask about.